# PostGIS can't find GDALALLRegister

Tags: postgresql, curl, postgis

I'm trying to install PostGIS on a webserver (debian) without root. When I run ./configure it throws this error:

```
checking for library containing GDALALLRegister... no
configure: error: could not find GDAL
```

config.log has this:
[config.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWukB.png)

The system I'm working on has curl, but I've also installed curl and libcurl4-openssl-dev locally (in /home/.local/)

I should also add that the system seems to already have all required libraries for gdal, according to gdal-config --dep-libs

Comment: You may be able to set the GDAL version / location via an environment variable prior to running configure?

Comment: the strange thing is it can find gdal-config, so it should be able to find GDAL, but I've also set `export GDAL_DATA=/home/.local/share/gdal` and it hasn't helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually fixed this, for posterity, I had to install a local copy of curl using the latest version of openssl, then recompile gdal using this version of curl.